# How to make jQuery Tools Scrollable RTL or Start from last item?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, right-to-left, scrollable

I am using [jQUery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html)

to create a scrollable with navigation that autoscrolls.
Now the autoscroll starts with the first item from the left 
(makes sense)
Now my question how can i make it RTL?
I belive making the autoscroll start from the end to the begining would do the trick
much easier.

Any one knows how the hell do i do that?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is supported by the plugin... you will have to modify its code.

Here is one example from the flowplayer forum,

[autoscroll with reversed direction](http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/35/64726)

Comment: Wow first of all thanks for finding this i've been looking for 2 hours! secondly, i need to insert it instead of some stuff in the js file or add it?

Answer (score 0):

official answer link doesn't work any more. with current tools, you'd want something like this after creating the scrollable item #scroller:

$("#scroller").data("scrollable").next = function(time) { return this.move(-1, time); };

you're overwriting the "next" function to move backwards instead of forwards. this was all we needed along with autoscroll, but you'd do the same with ".prev" to reverse the direction there as well.